# MacBook Pro external monitor resolution differences between HDMI and Thunderbolt ports?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have a mid-2012 Retina MacBook Pro with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M PCIe GPU. This notebook has an HDMI port and two Thunderbolt 1 ports. I've read many conflicting posts whether or not this notebook can handle a 2160p external monitor. The official Apple stance has apparently been to avoid the question entirely. The consensus appears to be that it can but only at 30 Hz and I question this reasoning. The GeForce GT 650M can handle 3840x2160 resolution and any external monitor using HDMI will use this GPU. Therefore, why wouldn't this notebook be able to handle a 2160p monitor at 60 Hz? Furthermore, many posts recommend using the Thunderbolt port for a 2160p external monitor but is that really going to get better performance (higher resolution and refresh rate) than HDMI?